# Trying install python-psycopg2 breaks Ubuntu 16.04 apt

Tags: python, psycopg2, apt

After trying to install python-psycopg2 with

```
sudo apt install python-psycopg2
```

`apt` breaks and I cannot even purge that package.

I've got an error when I try to purge with

```
sudo apt purge python-psycopg2
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-egenix-mxtools (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
Configurando python-psycopg2 (2.6.1-1build2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-psycopg2 (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 1
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 python-egenix-mxtools
 python-psycopg2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already try

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install -f
```

without success.

I'm using python 3.5. Is it possible that the broken issue caused by trying to install python-psycopg2 instead python3-psycopg2?

I'm halted here. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should install the right version of the library for your Python version. If a `python3-psycopg2` package exists you should install that; however note that it is not generally recommended to use your distribution's packages to install Python libraries, since they are usually out of date. Instead you should use `pip` (or `pip3`) to install libraries directly from the Python packaging index.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I just catch the error here. I've changed symbolic link `python` that was pointing to `python2.7`, to point to `python3.5`. And now when `apt` called python, it was running `python3.5` and not `python2.7`, and gave incompatibility when dealing with python-psycopg2. Thanks for the tip about `pip3`.

Comment: You really shouldn't change anything about your system Python; you're likely to break all sorts of things.